# Crawling websites with Nutch 2.3.1 skips product links but crawls other links

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

So, I am trying to crawl men shoes from jabong.com.

My seed url is:

```
http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/
```

I am making sure nutch does no skip `?` and `=` using this is `regex-urlfilter.txt`:

```
-[*!@]
```

This is my `protocol.includes` in nutch-site.xml:

```
protocol-httpclient|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)|indexer-solr
```

It crawls links like the following and I can search them in solr:

```
http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/andrew-hill/
http://www.jabong.com/men/shoes/?sh_size=40
http://www.jabong.com/all-products/?promotion=app-10-promo&cmpgp=takeover5
```

But it is not crawling products that I want to crawl actually. Product links are:

```
http://www.jabong.com/Alberto-Torresi-Black-Sandals-2024892.html?pos=2
http://www.jabong.com/Clarks-Un-Walk-Brown-Formal-Shoes-874785.html?pos=11
```

This is weird because these links are there in the same page as the seed URL, but they are not getting crawled. I did a `wget` to get the page and saw the links are there so no javascript involved.

What mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page navigation doesn't depend on cookie. Try  dumping the crawlDB and segments and check is the expected urls has been navigated or not. If navigated what contents has been fetched from this url.